# Analysing the complexity of a recurrent function i+1,j*2

Tags: algorithm-analysis

Let's say we start with $i = 1$, $j = 1$, $i \leq n$, and $j \leq i$ and
then increment $i = i+1$ and $j = 2j$, respectively.  The output prints
$k$ times, which represents the inner loop.
Output: `print s` $k$ times.

Example when $n=5$, loop will print 11 times.  How to find the
complexity function of this algorithm for $n=5$?

So far, I figured out the pattern for $n=5$, $p = 1+(2+2)+(3+3)$ which
can be generalized by $k \cdot 2^{k-1}$ for $n$ size
$1+(2+2)+(3+3+3+3)+\dots$.

The answer is $$((n+1)\log(n+1)+1)-(2^{(\log n+1)})$$ by the summation
$k \cdot 2^{k-1}$—constant when $k=1$ to $p$.

How do I go from summation to this answer?

What value should be $P$ if I do summation from $k=1$ to $P:1+(2+2)+(3+3)$?

Comment: Thanks, Pai GD for making it simpler. :)

Comment: I dont think I understood the question. Can you elaborate of the specifics on why the loop would run 11 times if $n=5$. What are the stopping conditions here?